# my javascript string is like this: "accepted === accepted && 50 > 100" Now I have to return boolean ans about this string which is valid or not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eval

I am creating one dynamic condition builder and it will return me a javascript string like,
`tpc_1 === accepted && tpc_6 > 100`
After replace function my new string is,
`accepted === accepted && 50 > 100`

Now I have to check if this string is valid as a javascript string or not?

I need the only boolean answer in return. So I decided to use the eval() function. When I passed eval(condition) **condition is variable which stores my string** it will show me the error like *

> accepted is not defined

- 

and when I passed as eval('condition') in the console it will simply be written in the console  `accepted === accepted && 50 > 100`.

So how to solve this issue. Please help me on this.

Comment: accepted === accepted needs to be actually a string.

that is "accepted "=== "accepted", the reason why you are getting "is not defined"

Comment: also, worth checking below, mdn advises not to use eval

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 1, accepted):

accepted is considered as variable when `eval` evaluates. So you have mention string with quotes.
Try this `eval("'accepted' === 'accepted' && 50 > 100")`;

Comment: As I mentioned in my question my string is dynamic and every time the string and the operator(inside the string-like ===, >, !==, etc) are different so how can I evaluate my string?

Answer (score 1):

The accepted need to be in  a quotes

```
eval('"accepted" === "accepted" && 50 > 100')
```

Comment: As I mentioned in my question my string is dynamic and every time the string and the operator(inside the string-like ===, >, !==, etc) are different so how can I evaluate my string?

Answer (score 0):

You can interpolate variables using template literal as below.

```
eval(`"${tpc_1}" === "accepted" && ${tpc_6} > 100`)
```

Comment: you should escape `"` char on `tcp_1` variable

Comment: As I mentioned in my question my string is dynamic and every time the string and the operator(inside the string-like ===, >, !==, etc) are different so how can I evaluate my string?

Comment: dynamically?. give some additional information or examples